# Express the raw sql into Django notation object filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to express the following raw sql into django notation with filter ?

```
    for p in wm.user_visibility.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM user S 
                                             LEFT JOIN user_visibility SA
                                             ON S.Id = SA.user_id AND SA.dash_id=' + param + 
                                             'WHERE  SA.user_id IS NULL'): 
        print(p.full_name)
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? NB: you may want to [read this](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

Answer (score 0):

```
user_visibility.objects.filter(dash_id = param, user_id__isnull = True)
```

#### P.s.

Your SQL is weird. Joining `user` and `user_visibility` on `user_id`, but then keep only entries where `user_visibility.user_id` is null.